# Qual é a finalidade de { } (chaves) poder ser usada para delimitar de código em PHP?

Tags: php, sintaxe

No PHP, é possível utilizar os chaves em qualquer trecho de código, por exemplo, para separar blocos esteticamente.

Exemplo:

```
{ $a = 1; }

{
    class X{}
}

{
    {
        function x() {}
    }
}
```

Nesses exemplos, nenhum deles um erro é gerado.

Entendo perfeitamente a importância da utilização do parêntesis em alguns casos. Como nesse exemplo:

```
($a + $b) * $c;

$a + ($b * $c);
```

Porém, quanto às chaves, qual é a finalidade de o PHP permitir isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.intro.php)

> Qualquer script PHP é construído por uma série de instruções. Uma
>   instrução pode ser uma atribuição, uma chamada de função, um 'loop',
>   uma instrução condicional, ou mesmo uma instrução que não faz nada (um
>   comando vazio). Instruções geralmente terminam com um ponto e vírgula.
>   Além disso, as instruções podem ser agrupados em um grupo de comandos
>   através do encapsulamento de um grupo de comandos com chaves. Um grupo
>   de comandos é uma instrução também. Os vários tipos de instruções são
>   descritos neste capítulo.

Apesar de muito mal escrito ou traduzido, quer dizer que é possível agrupar blocos de comandos, como por exemplo quando utiliza um `if` ou um `for`, essas instruções irão executar o próximo comando ou bloco de comando.

```
// Executando o próximo comando.
if ($foo == $bar)
     echo 'comando a ser executado';

// Executando o próximo bloco de comando.
if ($foo == $bar) {
     echo 'inicio do bloco de comando';
     echo 'meio do bloco de comando';
     echo 'final do bloco de comando';
}
```

Outra forma de uso das chaves é para usar variáveis no meio de strings iniciadas com aspas duplas.

```
$str = "Uma string contendo a váriavel {$teste}";
$str = "Uma string apresentando um atributo {$this->teste}";
$str = "Uma string apresentando uma posição de um atributo {$this->teste[1]}";
```

As chaves não iniciam um novo escopo de código, apenas agrupam um grupo de comandos.

Uma outra aplicação para isso muito usual em C# conhecido como regions é agrupar códigos para documentação, mas sinceramente acho que só polui o código.

```
// Comentando o bloco seguinte de ações
{
    echo 'imprime alguma coisa';
    $a = 2;
    $b = 3;
    $c = 4;
    $x = $a + $b * $c;
    echo $x;
}
```

Com o agrupamento de código acima, em alguns editores você poderá contrair o código omitindo-o.

Comment: +1 por "muito mal escrito ou traduzido", pq é mesmo!

Comment: Pelo simples facto de o _PHP_ permitir estruturar o código das mais diversas formas possíveis, apresentando compatibilidade com outras linguagens a nível semântico, pode-se afirmar que servem apenas para ajudar na leitura, e localizar cadeias de código com mesma finalidade com mais facilidade.

Comment: Exatamente @Edilson

Comment: kkk obrigado @rray, triste mas verdade ne? rs fazer o que

Comment: [Leia a primeira frase](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.interfaces.php) e veja se encontra algum erro.

Comment: Não olhei erro de português, mas como assim métodos e variáveis? ele está se referindo a atributos obrigatórios ou parâmetros dos métodos? kkk ficou parecendo atributos da classe, e até onde sei não podem ser especificados em interfaces, apenas constantes o.O

Comment: Não é erro de português, é isso ai que você falou => bizarro.

Comment: Na verdade, entende-se que o PHP tem muitas funcionalidades inúteis. Nunca vi ninguém usando isso, nem mesmo a documentação explica isso (direto). Vi isso em um código de um programador que anteriormente programava em C#

Comment: Eu penso o seguinte, se precisa criar regions, pode muito bem refatorar e transformar em métodos ou funções, assim vc melhora a legibilidade e ainda reaproveita código.